# PHP unserialize an object without the matching class

Tags: php, serialization

I have database rows containing serialized objects.

I want to deserialize these, but the class has changed, some properties went private so the deserialization no longer works.

Is there a way to force deserialization to an array or a stdClass? (or anything that won't cause an error upon deserialization)

I want to avoid migrating data with a script. I'd rather have backward compatibility with the objects serialized in the old format.

Comment: Not to be sarcastic or anything, but: *That's* why you don't store *code* in a database... :)

Comment: @deceze Amen to that. NEVER AGAIN! -_-

Comment: This is why you don't store objects as serialized strings to a database.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not really, or at least i would be pretty afraid to use something like this in production.
However, `unserialize` will use the autoload system or the function name specified in the `unserialize_callback_func` ini setting. So with a little hacking you can make this work:

```
// this a serialized object with the class "SomeMissingClass"
$str = 'O:16:"SomeMissingClass":1:{s:1:"a";s:1:"b";}';
ini_set('unserialize_callback_func', 'define_me'); // set your callback_function

// unserialize will pass in the desired class name
function define_me($classname) {
    // just create a class that has some nice accessors to it
    eval("class $classname extends ArrayObject {}");
}
$object = unserialize($str);
print $object['a']; // should print 'b'
```

You can use something like this to migrate your data to a little more handy format.

## UPDATE:

I've consulted with my repressed memories on this (i've faced something like this once) and remembered an other solution:

So you have your `SomeClass` with a `private` property named `$a`

```
class SomeClass {
    private $a;
    public function getA(){
        return $this->a;
    }
}
```

And you have the serialized version of it:

```
$str = 'O:9:"SomeClass":1:{s:1:"a";s:1:"b";}';
```

When you unserialize it, and dump the result it will look like this, which is no good:

```
$a = unserialize($str);
var_dump($a->getA()); // prints 'null'
var_dump($a);
/* 
prints:
object(SomeClass)#1 (2) {
   ["a":"SomeClass":private]=>
   NULL
   ["a"]=>
   string(1) "b"
}
*/
```

Now, when an object get's unserialized, php will call it's `__wakeup` magic method. The data you need is there in the object, but not under the private property but a similarly named public one. You can't reach that with the `$this->a` since it will look for the wrong one,
however the method [`get_object_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) will return these properties and you can reassign them inside a `__wakeup()`:

```
class SomeClass {
    private $a;
    public function getA(){
        return $this->a;
    }
    public function __wakeup(){
        foreach (get_object_vars($this) as $k => $v) {
            $this->{$k} = $v;
        }
    }
}
$str = 'O:9:"SomeClass":1:{s:1:"a";s:1:"b";}';
$a = unserialize($str);
print $a->getA();
```

I think it's needless to say that you should save yourself the further headache and convert your data to some dedicated data exchange format.

Comment: Wow, that's clever and horrifying at the same time!

Comment: Thanks for the crazy ideas! This is awesome, I will use it to migrate softly to a more sensible data format than serialized objects :)

Answer (score -1):

Aside from manually munging the data in the database itself, which is always a risky proposition, I think your only option is to roll back the class code to an older version, extract the data, then re-store it in a more sensible way that can be more easily dealt with in future code revisions.

You do have the old classes in your SVN/GIT/CVS, right?

Comment: Yes yes I do, like I said I'd like to avoid a migration step *if possible*.