# Analyse/parse a serialized PHP data containining objects?

Tags: php

My problem is that I have a list of serialized objects in a database, and I want to display a list of the details of those object to the user through an admin page. They are PHP objects in a Laravel queue.

I don't want to `unserialize()` the data to restore the original objects, I just need to be able to "look in" at what is there.

One approach may be to convert each object in the serialized string to a `stdClass` and move the original class name to a property of that. There may be other ways to analyse the string and provide what it contains as nested arrays of data.

Are there any implementations of these, or other, approaches available? I've not found anything in my usual searches.

Comment: That will try to instantiate all the objects it contains, some of which will not be available, and none of which I need as instantiated objects. I just need to look at some of the object names, and pull out some object properties, and they will be what the user sees, and will be useful to the user. It is for an admin page that lists jobs queued in the database, and those jobs are defined as a mix of JSON serialised data and PHP `serialized` data.

Comment: Sounds like a huge effort compared to simply instantiating the objects...

Comment: If you need to access object attributes, then you _do_ need them as objects not as a serialized string. At least it doesn't make sense in my opinion to parse that string to find what you want instead of unserializing the objects and access the values that way.

Comment: Except the objects are often *not available*. The objects that are not available cannot be instantiated as objects, because they are not available. Surely a PHP serialized string is just data, object names and attributes alike, and that data is not too complex to be parsed. Has this never been done in PHP before? Or is the structure of a serialized string really that much more complex than I am imagining it is.

Comment: Did you check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338057/php-unserialize-an-object-without-the-matching-class? If I understand what you're asking correctly, he is attempting to do something very similar.

Comment: That is very a neat trick, and *almost* there. Using the `unserialize_callback_func` ini setting allows you to create and object of any class you like in place of a class that is no longer available. In my case, I would rather not instantiate any of the classes, or at a minimum replace them all with a stdClass, but it may possible be the route I have to go. But that's a very neat trick to know, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question, much that it ruffles me.

I have written a quick package that does the parsing - just a couple of classes. It won't parse ALL serialized data that you can throw at it, but it works with everything I need it for just now.

Here it is, in case it is of any use:

https://github.com/academe/SerializeParser

There are a number of non-PHP packages around that do this parsing, and I just migrated some of the code from those to scratch an itch.